# Laravel mimes validation rule not working for some file extensions

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm trying to use `mimes` validation rule to validate uploading file.

```
'attachment' => 'required|file|max:1024|mimes:png,gif,jpg,txt,pdf,doc,docx,zip,rar'
```

It's working for some files with extensions like `php` but It's not working for extensions like `js apk ovpn ....`

Any idea?

Comment: Do the files you're attempting to upload have extensions which accurately represent their contents?

Comment: @alaric Yes, I can upload `.js` files (tested)

Answer (score 0):

Your messages error look like what before your validation. They should look like this

```
$messages = [
            "attachment.required" => "error required",
            "attachment.mimes" => "error mines",
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'attachment' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt',
        ], $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/home')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        } else {
          // your code here
        }
```

can you detail your file little more